# How do I loop through dictionaries and extract values, one for each time looped?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries that I want to loop through simultaneously and extract the same indexed value from.

I've tried appending values to a list and indexing that way, but I may have gotten the code wrong. Also, I tried using the 'iteritems' and '.values()' functions, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to do that using those.

```
color = {'red' : 1, 'blue' : 2, 'green' : 3}
fruit = {'cherry' : 4, 'berry' : 5, 'apple' : 6}
levels = [1000, 925, 850, 700, 500, 400, 300, 250, 200, 150, 100]
levels.sort()
i = 0
while i < 3:
    for j in color.values()[i]:
        for k in fruit.values()[i]:
            print j
            print k
            print '%s mb EDR Normalized Anomalies' % (levels[i])
            i += 1
```

This code doesn't work obviously, but this is essentially what I want it to do. I want the loops to print out the first value in color (1) and the first value in fruit (4). How the code is set up currently, it would print out the first value in color, print out all values for fruit, then repeat for the second value of color. I don't want that either. Just the same indexed value for each dictionary.

Comment: Generally, order is not guaranteed in dictionaries. You probably want to use `collections.OrderedDict` instead.

Comment: Dictionaries are inherently not ordered - definitely not in Python 2.7 (judging by your `print` statement). How do you want to pair colors to fruits then?

Comment: Yes, I would use the OrderedDict function, although for the purposes of this question, it's not a deal breaker. I want the first loop to print 1 and 4, the second to print 2 and 5, and the third to print 3 and 6.

Comment: As of Python 3.7, the dictionary retains the insertion order of the keys for use by its iterators.

Comment: @ak_cira As others have pointed out, you are using Python 2. And in Python 2, the way you have declared the dictionaries does not guarantee order, i.e. you cannot guarantee a pairing of 1 to 4, 2 to 5 and 3 to 6. In that sense, ordering _is_ a deal breaker.

Comment: The bigger issue here is that I get one value from each dict, not so much that they match. This is a simplified version of a different script I'm working with. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for `zip()`:

```
for f, c in zip(color.values(), fruit.values()):
    print(f)
    print(c)
```

Not 100% sure I correctly understand your question though.

Edit: Thanks to the people who pointed out I was overwriting color and fruit. Indeed, this only works in case the dictionary is ordered already, but from the example I understood this was already the case.

Comment: It won't work in all cases as the order is not guaranteed in python dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `collections.OrderedDict` or something like it to guarantee ordering in a dictionary-like object. Then you can just zip the items.

Here, I print all associated keys and values. Pick and choose to your liking.

**Code:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

color = OrderedDict({'red' : 1, 'blue' : 2, 'green' : 3})
fruit = OrderedDict({'cherry' : 4, 'berry' : 5, 'apple' : 6})

for x, y in zip(color.items(), fruit.items()):
    print(x[0], y[0], x[1], y[1])
```

**Output:**

```
red cherry 1 4
blue berry 2 5
green apple 3 6
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can just get the values and not both the keys and values to print?

Comment: `OrderedDict` (as of Python 3.7) is only needed if the insertion order is relevant for dict equality; otherwise, the iteration order of an ordinary `dict` is fixed and predictable.

Comment: @ak_cira `print(x[1], y[1])` shows just the values.

Comment: @chepner He is using Python 2.x Look at the print statements.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, dicionnaries in Python are not ordered. However, you can use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
color = OrderedDict({'red' : 1, 'blue' : 2, 'green' : 3})
fruit = OrderedDict({'cherry' : 4, 'berry' : 5, 'apple' : 6})
```

Then, you can use the zip function :

```
for c,f in zip(color.values(), fruit.values()):
    print(c, f)
```

Comment: Dictionaries as of Python 3.7 *are* ordered, at least from the perspective of the iteration.

Comment: Yes but not in the same order you declared the dictionary. OrderedDict is a way to avoid that problem

Comment: That's what insertion order means. That they **are** ordered by the ordered you declared them...